# AdMob never loads on certain devices

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I've got a decent app on the Play Store with a few thousand users and I've been using AdMob interstitials and banners for a few years now. Recently I've noticed that on some devices the ads never load.

I've checked everything and I've been scratching my head now for a few days. On these devices, AdMob is initialized, but interstitials and banners never load.

```
        MobileAds.initialize( this, (InitializationStatus initializationStatus) -> {
        Log.d( TAG, "initAds: " + initializationStatus );
        loadInterstitialAd();
        //loadRewardedVideoAd();
    } );
```

> The above returns com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzahg@xxxxxx

Anyone with any similar experiences?

Every time I try to show an advert, the status of the interstitial is 'loading'. This perhaps happening on about 10-15% of all of my client devices and one of my simulators with Android API 22.

I have also checked my logs and I can say that these devices are varied with Android 8,9 & 10 and devices from Samsung, LGE, Motorola and Google.

I have even tried using the test ad unit ID. The result is the same.

### Update->Code

```
  private void loadInterstitialAd() {
    if (mInterstitialAd == null) {
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd( MainActivity.this );
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId( ADMOB_INTERSTITIAL );//REAL
    }

    List<String> testDevices = new ArrayList<>();
    testDevices.add(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
    testDevices.add( ADMOB_TEST_DEVICE_1 );
    testDevices.add( ADMOB_TEST_DEVICE_2 );
    RequestConfiguration requestConfiguration
            = new RequestConfiguration.Builder()
            .setTestDeviceIds(testDevices)
            .build();
    MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(requestConfiguration);

    final AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd( request );


    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener( new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            //Log.d( TAG, "onAdClosed: Before" );
            new Handler().postDelayed( () -> EventBus.getDefault().post( new MessageEvent( EVENT_MESSAGE_ADMOB, EVENT_ACTION_AD_FINISHED, new Bundle() ) ), 200 );
            //Log.d( TAG, "onAdClosed: After" );s
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd( request );
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            if (!mInterstitialAd.isLoading()) {
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd( request );
            }
            Log.d( TAG, "onAdFailedToLoad: " + errorCode );
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            Log.d( TAG, "onAdLoaded: " );
            super.onAdLoaded();
        }

    } );
    Log.d( TAG, "loadInterstitialAd: 4 " + (mInterstitialAd == null ? "NULL" : "NOT NULL") );
}



  public void showInterstitial() {
    Log.d( TAG, "showInterstitial: 0" );
    try {
        if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
            Log.d( TAG, "showInterstitial: 1" );
        } else {
            EventBus.getDefault().post( new MessageEvent( EVENT_MESSAGE_ADMOB, EVENT_ACTION_AD_FINISHED, new Bundle() ) );
            loadInterstitialAd();
            Log.d( TAG, "showInterstitial: 2" );
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( mContext ).edit();
            editor.putLong( "mLastAdShownTime" + appSuffix, 0 );
            editor.commit();

        }
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoading()) {
            Log.d( TAG, "showInterstitial: LOADING" );
            Crashlytics.log( TAG + " -showInterstitial - " + getAccountID( mContext ) );
            Crashlytics.logException( new RuntimeException() );
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d( TAG, "showInterstitial: 3" );
        Crashlytics.log( TAG + " -showInterstitial - " + e.toString() );
        Crashlytics.logException( e );
        EventBus.getDefault().post( new MessageEvent( EVENT_MESSAGE_ADMOB, EVENT_ACTION_AD_FINISHED, new Bundle() ) );
        e.printStackTrace();
        loadInterstitialAd();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( mContext ).edit();
        editor.putLong( "mLastAdShownTime" + appSuffix, 0 );
        editor.commit();

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share detail code snippets of load ads and show ads.

Comment: Hi Daxesh, I've updated the thread with my load and show codes. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: It is an issue of some certain devices, right?

Comment: and please remove load ads from onAdFailedToLoad()  because

Attempting to load a new ad from the onAdFailedToLoad() method is strongly discouraged. If you must load an ad from onAdFailedToLoad(), limit ad load retries to avoid continuously failed ad requests in situations such as limited network connectivity.

Comment: In the code, you have set live ads id and set 2 test device. but if test device id is not match with code then it did not work so better to set test interstitial id while you testing your app.

Comment: I still don't understand this. I've used this code until Ads 18.2. The problem started occurring only after Ads 18.2.I'll try removing test devices and update the aab today. Let's see how that makes a change. I'll keep the thread update.

Answer (score 0):

While you working on debug mode make sure you set test ads id because Admob never serves live ads before app publish.

Test App id:  ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713

[Test Ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads)

**Declare in manifest**

```
  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713" />
```

**Code Snippet**

```
private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    loadFullscreenAd();
}

private void loadFullscreenAd() {

    if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
        if (!mInterstitialAd.isLoading() && !mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
        return;
    }
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getActivity());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            loadFullscreenAd();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {

            loadFullscreenAd();
        }
    });
}

 public void showFullScreenAds() {
    if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }else if(!mInterstitialAd.isLoading()){
            loadFullscreenAd();
        }
    }else {
        loadFullscreenAd();
    }
}
```